# Unable to copy parquet data from S3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, parquet

I want to be able to copy parquet data from S3 to Redshift.

I have tried the code below:

```
-- Part 1: Unload
SET search_path TO my_schema_from;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
  column1   VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO my_table (column1) VALUES ('abc');

UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM my_table') TO 's3://my_bucket/my_table_' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::my_role' 
FORMAT AS PARQUET
ALLOWOVERWRITE
MANIFEST;

-- Part 2: Copy
SET search_path TO my_schema_to;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
  column1   VARCHAR
);

COPY my_table 
FROM 's3://my_bucket/my_table_manifest' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::my_role' 
FORMAT AS PARQUET
MANIFEST;
```

Part 1 looks to run as expected. However, Part 2 errors with:

```
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Spectrum Scan Error
  code:      15007
  context:   Forbidden: HTTP response error code: 403 Message: AccessDenied Access Denied
```

The error is saying there are access issues.

My IAM role has `AmazonS3FullAccess` associated to it - I have tested that it can successfully move data between S3 and redshift because if I change the format from `FORMAT AS PARQUET` to `FORMAT AS CSV` in both parts, it works as expected.

As the error is saying spectrum is involved, I have tried updating the IAM role to give it the access required, but with no success - I have tried adding glue but no change, it still errors...

(I know in the simplified example that CSV would work, I need the files on S3 to be in parquet for another process).

Comment: It would be helpful if you put the relevant parts of the role in your question. My _guess_ is that loading from Parquet requires `ListBucket` even with a manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated the description accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For Spectrum, it seems that Redshift requires additional roles/IAM permissions. [This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html) mentions:

> For Redshift Spectrum, in addition to Amazon S3 access, add **AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess** or **AmazonAthenaFullAccess**.

Redshift Spectrum uses the Glue Data Catalog, and needs access to it, which is granted by above roles. Of course, you should limit the access in your role to the required parts of and actions in the data catalog.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I mentioned though that I have already tried adding glue permissions but it still errors ...